# A set is always subset and member of its successor?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I'm studying a subject on axiomatic set theory (Zermelo-Fraenkel). One of the books we use is Elements of set theory by Herbert Enderton.

Enderton (and the notes) define for any set $a$, the successor $a^+$ by
\begin{equation}
a^+ = a \cup \lbrace a \rbrace
\end{equation}
Now they say that a set $A$ is transitive iff:
\begin{align}
\forall a \forall x (x \in a \wedge a \in A \rightarrow x\in A)
\end{align}
Now i have to prove (exercise given by a teacher):
If $A$ is a transitive set, then $A \in A^+$ and $A \subseteq A^+$.

My question, it is necessary that $A$ be a transitive set? I mean it is not obvious that always $A \in A^+$ and $A \subseteq A^+$? Because in another book use this fact to prove a lot of things (Patrick Suppes).

Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You are right, it is obvious by definition and does not require transitivity.

Comment: You are exactly right. if it required transitivity, every set would be transitive, ( can you imagine any counterexamples?)  A more interesting example might be: Assume A is transitive, prove that the successor of A is transitive. This result follows, immediately from the claim in your post. Which I imagine is why your teacher phrases it this way.